# How to Display Text in SystemTray

Tags: windows-phone-8, system-tray

First off, is this possible, and how. I've seen some Microsoft apps, such as the Bing Weather App, where the SystemTray is displayed without the progress indicator moving. I'd like to implement the same, and be able to toggle whether the progress indicator is on or off when required. How might I implement this sort of feature?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how:

```
ProgressIndicator progress = new ProgressIndicator
{
    IsVisible = true,
    IsIndeterminate = true,
    Text = "Downloading details..."
};
SystemTray.SetProgressIndicator(this, progress);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very well explained here

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/shubham0987/how-to-use-progress-indicator-in-windows-phone/

Also if you do not want the Progress Bar you can replace there "SetProgressIndicator" function with this

```
private void SetProgressIndicator(bool value)
{
    SystemTray.ProgressIndicator.IsIndeterminate = false;
    SystemTray.ProgressIndicator.IsVisible = value
}
```